# select option default does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, html-select

I have 3 select tags in my page and i wan to set a default value selected for them. I searched  a way to do this and it works for one but does not for the other to. i cant find the problem here.
I get the values I want here:

```
String start =String.valueOf(rule.getStart());
String end =String.valueOf(rule.getEnd());
String numberOfCars = String.valueOf(rule.getNumberOfCars());
```

I have tested the values and they are correct.
these are my select tags:

```
<select id="numberOfCars" name="numberOfCars">
            <option value="1">1</option>            
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="1">4</option>            
            <option value="2">5</option>
            <option value="3">6</option>
            <option value="1">7</option>            
            <option value="2">8</option>
            <option value="3">9</option>
            <option value="3">10</option>
        </select>

<select id="startHour" name="startHour">
            <option value="0">0</option>                    
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>   
        </select>
<select id="endHour" name="endHour" >
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
        </select>
```

and here are the functions that I found. the one for start works perfectly but the other 2 does not and I cant find the reason:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$("#endHour option:selected").length)
$("#endHour option[value='<%=end%>']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 if (!$("#numberOfCars option:selected").length)
$("#numberOfCars option[value='<%=numberOfCars%>']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 if (!$("#starHour option:selected").length)
$("#startHour option[value='<%=start%>']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `startHour` select works because of an error in the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if (!$("#starHour option:selected").length)  //Notice its starHour not startHour
$("#startHour option[value='<%=start%>']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

By default an option within the select will be set to selected, which causes your code within the conditional block not to execute.  StartHour executes because of the error in the selector which causes the value to be 0.

Try removing the conditional blocks:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#endHour option[value='<%=end%>']").attr('selected', 'selected');
     $("#startHour option[value='<%=start%>']").attr('selected', 'selected');
     $("#numberOfCars option[value='<%=numberOfCars%>']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
</script>
```

Here is a really simple example illustrating the basic problem, which is that an option is selected by default. http://jsfiddle.net/fVjzw/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$("#endHour option:selected").length)
$("#endHour option[value='<%=end%>']").attr('selected', true);
});
</script>
```

If my memory serves you should do it this way. And you should merge them all in same  tag. Why to spread them?